# How to load JSON to array ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json

I created JSON online because i have to insert JSON to Database that i used locally.

So till now i created JSON from online that is :

```
{
  "City": [
    "Anaheim",
    "Surat",
    "Aheldaba",
    "Vadobasa"
  ],
  "State": [
    "Gujarat",
    "Pennsylvania",
    "MP",
    "ULK"
      ],

  ",string": ",Hello World"
}
```

Now i have to take this JSON to my array so i can easy add this to database.

what is the way to add this JSON directly yo array ?

Comment: show your tried code always

Comment: can i copy direct this JSON to array ?

Comment: ya sure, you can diretcly use it

Comment: @KaviPatel Json to array not dictionary?

Comment: Put it into a file in your resources, load the `NSData` from that file and parse  that data using `NSJSONSerialization`.

Comment: i didn't get this json from any where i created that json by myself, so now how i copy to array ?

Comment: @Sulthan Thnx bro, that's what i want to do. I did it. Again thanks.

Comment: Any chance to try SwiftyJSON? https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: @SavaMazăre This is objective-c.

Comment: @Sulthan, this is 2017 )))

Answer (score 0):

Try with it.

```
NSString *jsonString = @"your json string";
NSData *jSONObjectWithData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *jsonError = nil;
id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization jSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert your json string to NSData by doing the following

```
NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSError *parsingError = nil;

NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&parsingError];

NSArray *cityArray = [json objectForKey:@"City"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (data) {
                NSError* error;
                NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                                      JSONObjectWithData:data //1
                                      options:kNilOptions
                                      error:&error];
    if(!error){

    id totalRecords = json.mutableCopy;//[json objectForKey:@"hits"];

         if ([totalRecords isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                    NSArray *records =[totalRecords objectForKey:@"data"];

          }
          else if ([totalRecords isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
                    NSArray *records =totalRecords.mutableCopy;

           }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can create a kind of dictionary or you say key value pair. but, definitely you have to take the pain of converting the son string to data using `UTFStringEncoding` and then to supply that to `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObject()` for key value pairs.

```
class JSON{
    func convertJSON(){
        do{
            let data:NSData? = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let json = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)
            print(json)
        }
        catch {
            print("Error is \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```